# Send file to Azure Storage BLOB from SAP

Tags: azure, azure-storage, sap-pi, sap-data-services

How is it possible to send a file to Azure Storage BLOB from SAP? Maybe SAP PI can do it?

I am standing ground on SAP matters. Any advice here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAP does support storing files in Azure Blob storage using the Azure Cloud Storage Protocol. You need to Define a File Location object for the ACSP. There is full documentation available on SAP's website [**here**](https://help.sap.com/viewer/e54136ab6a4a43e6a370265bf0a2d744/4.2.9/en-US/34aa8509f77f4e1fb0406308b9e2c4dd.html)